# Can I have an Alexa speechlet with only one "on" event?

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am new to Alexa SDK.  I have the HelloWorld speechlet up and running. I think I understand the difference between onLaunch (When session is null)  and onIntent (When it's not null)

But what if I just want something even simpler?  I want to just match a single utterance with a response. Both methods need to be implemented.

Is it correct to simply return a blank speech response?   If so,  should it be onLaunch or onIntent? What am I mis understanding?

Comment: which language are you using? can you provide more details like what sdk (language) are interested in.

Comment: Sorry,  I am using the Java SDK with the 1.1.2 skils kit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the `onLaunch` intent refers to the start of your Alexa skill which should map to a Welcome or Start application response.  So if you execute an onLaunch intent you respond with a Welcome msg & some instructions on how to use the Alex Skill. onLaunch only fires when the user utters the statement to open the app like:

> Alexa open hello world

It's the default response upon initialization of the skill

The `onIntent` will fire for all **non-onLaunch** intents. The `Intents` & `Utterance` statement mappings are key here. Whatever audible is heard from Alexa is then processed & compared to the utterance statements defined in the your Utterance section of the apps Developer Portal. for example:

**Sample Utterances**

```
HelloWorldIntent say hello
HelloWorldIntent say hello world
HelloWorldIntent hello
```

When a user utters something like:

> Alexa open helloworld and say hello

The Skill initializes & detects the `say hello` phrase then maps it to the `HelloWorldIntent` which fires the onIntent() & processes the intent that is passed in the post request. The onIntent() will process the intent & return the response speech.

Comment: You say "if" I execute an onLaunch intent -- How do I not do that and just launch the onIntent method?

Comment: mmaceachran I've updated my answer to include some more detail hope this helps

Comment: I am starting to get it.  But I don't think your statement in the first paragraph is correct.  Because when I say "Alexa say hello"  it fires BOTH the onLaunch and onIntent.  I seem to be able to get around this bu returning a SpeechletResponse with a zero length String, but that does not seem right to me.  I want to be able to just map an Inetent to the onIntent method and go from there.

Comment: maybe you can post the code so we can take a look. I primarily use the python SDKs.  The behavior you're describing doesn't sound right.

Comment: I have a feeling that this might be an issue with your Invocation Phrase in the Developer portal.  I would recommend reading this doc & ensure you understand the Navigation. Voice UI is obv different & can be a pain to understand in the begining https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/supported-phrases-to-begin-a-conversation

Comment: And that is exactly correct.  I was trying to override Alexa's base programming, and I was not doing very well.  :)  Once I understood how custom skills worked and are invoked, I am doing much better. Thank You all.

Comment: Good to hear! The voice nav takes min to wrap your head around initially but once the light bulb goes off it get much more fun... good luck!